# Getting undefined value from navigation - React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am getting undefined value when passing the value through navigate.

**Code to send a value to home Component**

```
if(result.status === 200)
        {
            if(user.work === "Worker")
            {
                navigate("/home", {
                    mail:user.email
                });
            }
            
        }
```

**Routing Code**

```
<Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

**Home Component**

```
const { location } = useLocation();
console.log(location);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the state in the navigate like this:

```
if (result.status === 200) {
  if (user.work === "Worker") {
    navigate("/home", {
      state: { mail: user.email },
    });
  }
}
```

and then you can see the state in the **Home component**:

```
const { state } = useLocation();
console.log(state);
```